# Possible causes of missing white spaces when decoding a Base64 stream to a pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, base64

In my java application I obtain a pdf from a B64 stream.  The result is converted to a pdf without white spaces.  Has anyone had this problem?  I don't know if the problem is the decoding/encoding base64 (I use jasperreport and java.common.codec) or other feature of the application (I see results as an e-mail attachment).

Thanks.  Michele

Comment: I would think that if there was a problem in the base64 encoding/decoding that you would not get a valid PDF.  As @joel mentioned, I'd check the initial PDF first.

Comment: Please check the following like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644419/itext-java-pdf-to-text-creation

Answer (score 0):

Where is the PDF being generated? Hard to say without having more information, but I'd guess that the PDF is probably being generated by a server somewhere ... I would troubleshoot the PDF generation process and make sure that it's creating the correct PDF file structure before even getting to the base 64 encoded stream.

Comment: I use jasper report .hjasper templates, i found that the version tha i used, 4-0-1 (quite old) generate b64 stream that badly treat whitespaces. I tried to upgrade the jasperreport.jar version with 4.1.1, now only SOME parts of it has whitespaces removed, i'm trying to see the meaning but now i thik that is a matter of bad template generation.

Comment: I have noticed that pdf is bad viewed in browser pdf viewre like google or other but is good viewed on pdf reader in pc, this is an example http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33469381/test.pdf.zip, the upper part is whitout whitespaces but lower has it.