# itextsharp , why is GetSingleSpaceWidth() returning 0 when a space is visually obvious?

Tags: itext

[image]

Hi All,

This is a question related to **itextsharp** version 5.5.13.1. I am using a custom LocationTextExtractionStrategy implementation to extract sensible words from a PDF document. I am calling the method **GetSingleSpaceWidth** of TextRenderInfo to determine when to 
join two adjacent blocks of characters into a single word as per the SFO link
[itext java pdf to text creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644419/itext-java-pdf-to-text-creation/34412033#34412033)

This approach has generally worked well. However, if you look at the attached document, the words "**Credit**" and "**Extended**" is giving me some problems.
Why are all the characters shown encircled in the screen capture returning a zero value for **GetSingleSpaceWidth**? This causes a problem . Instead of two separate words, my logic returns me one word "**CreditExtended**".

I understand that itextsharp5 is not supported any more. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated?

**Sample document**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pPyNRXvnUyIA2CeRrv05-H9q0sTUN97d

Comment: I'll have a look at your file later this week. One possible cause would be that the font in question does not have a space glyph at all and that the distance between "Credit" and "Extended" is achieved by explicitly moving the text insertion point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already conjectured in a comment, the cause is that the font in question does not contain a regular space glyph, or even more exactly, does not map any of its glyphs to the Unicode value U+0020 in its **ToUnicode** map.

If a font has a **ToUnicode** map, iText uses only the information from that map. Thus, iText does not identify a space glyph in that font, so it cannot provide the actual `SingleSpaceWidth` value and returns 0 instead.

---

The font in question is named **F5** and has this **ToUnicode** map:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
14 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
4 beginbfchar
<0004> <0041>
<0012> <0043>
<001C> <0045>
<002F> <0049>
endbfchar
1 beginbfrange
<0044> <0045> <004D>
endbfrange
13 beginbfchar
<0102> <0061>
<0110> <0063>
<011A> <0064>
<011E> <0065>
<0150> <0067>
<015D> <0069>
<016F> <006C>
<0176> <006E>
<017D> <006F>
<0189> <0070>
<018C> <0072>
<0190> <0073>
<019A> <0074>
endbfchar
5 beginbfrange
<01C0> <01C1> <0076>
<01C6> <01C7> <0078>
<0359> <0359> [<2026>]
<035A> <035B> <2018>
<035E> <035F> <201C>
endbfrange
1 beginbfchar
<0374> <2013>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

As you can see, there is no mapping to `<0020>`.

---

The use of fonts in this PDF page is quite funny, by the way:

Its body is (mostly) drawn using Calibri, but it uses two distinct PDF font objects for this, **F4** which uses **WinAnsiEncoding** from character 32 through 122, i.e. *including the space glyph*, and **F5** which uses **Identity-H** and provides the above quoted **ToUnicode** map *without a space glyph*. Each maximal sequence of glyphs without gap is drawn separately; if that whole sequence can be drawn using **F4**, that font is used, otherwise **F5** is used.

Thus, `CMI`, `(Credit`, and `sub-indexes` are drawn using **F4** while `I’ve`, `“Credit`, and `Extended”` are drawn using **F5**.

In your problem string `“Credit Extended”`, therefore, we see two consecutive sequences drawn using **F5**. Thus, you'll get a 0 `SingleSpaceWidth` both for the `“Credit` **t** and the `Extended”` **E**.

At first glance these are the only two consecutive sequences using **F5**, so you have that issue only there.

---

As a consequence you should develop a fallback strategy for the case of two consecutive characters both coming with a 0 `SingleSpaceWidth`, e.g. using something like a third of the font size.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer . Just one more advice. If I were to read the same document using the latest version of itext (version 7 I believe ) would I still need to implement the logic which you have suggested ?

Comment: I would *assume* so but I'm not sure. I'd have to test it.